# Проверка String на null

Tags: java, строки, null

Проверяю строку на `null`:

```
String str = null;
if(str == null){}
if(str.isEmpty())
if(str.equals(null))
```

Ничего не срабатывает.

Код:

```
String receiveTablet = new String();
receiveTablet = FindTabletTo(findTablet);
System.out.println(receiveTablet);
String check = null;
if(receiveTablet == null)
{
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Информация");
    alert.setHeaderText("Пожалуйста,внимательно прочти информацию");
    alert.setContentText("К сожаленю, по вашему запросу ничего не найдено");
    alert.showAndWait();
}
else {
    System.out.println("Вывод нового Stage");
}
```

`FindTabletTo` делает запрос в БД.

Comment: А можно полный и рабочий код, как проверяете, что ожидаете и что получаете?

Comment: Спасибо разобрался

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> String str = null;
> if(str == null){}
> if(str.isEmpty())
> if(str.equals(null))
> ```

Так как условие `str == null` истинно, то Вы зайдете в пустой блок и дальше перейдете к следующей строке, в которой получите `NullPointerException`, так как `str == null`.

По поводу второго фрагмента кода:

Вы создаете объект, и в `receiveTablet` находится ссылка на этот созданный объект. Далее Вы используете метод `FindTabletTo(...)`, который возвращает какой-то объект.

Если Вам нужно проверить строку `receiveTablet` на *отсутствие в ней содержимого* или на `null`, то:

- если `FindTabletTo(...)` не возвращает `null`, то можно просто:

  ```
  if (receiveTablet.isEmpty())
  ```
- если `FindTabletTo(...)` может вернуть `null`, то:

  ```
  if (receiveTablet == null || receiveTablet.isEmpty())
  ```

Comment: Последняя проверка вернет `true` только если receiveTablet не равна null и при этом пустая. Может быть, имелось в виду   `(receiveTablet == null || receiveTablet.isEmpty())` ?

Comment: @m.vokhm, Мной предполагалась проверка именно на отсутствие содержимого, поэтому нет. Но в контексте задачи, условие, предложенное Вами, является более полным. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score -2):

Если не работает:

```
if(str.equals(null){}
```

Попробуйте:

```
if(str.equals(""){}
```